# Binding Context by Relative Source

Tags: wpf, binding, relativesource

I would like to bind my DataTemplate (ClosableTabItemTemplate) to the Workspaces DataContext of the HeaderedContentControl by Relative Source. Unfortunately it doesn't work? Any ideas?

Btw:
I get the following command line error:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DisplayName' property not found on 'object' ''AllUserView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DisplayName; DataItem='TabItem' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')

Cya
Michael

```
<HeaderedContentControl 
      Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
      Header=""
      Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}" DataContext="{Binding}" 
                />
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel Width="120"  >
        <Button 
    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type HeaderedContentControl}}}"
    Content="X"
    Cursor="Hand"
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    Focusable="False"
    FontFamily="Courier" 
    FontSize="9"
    FontWeight="Bold"  
    Margin="0,1,0,0"
    Padding="0"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
    Width="16" Height="16" 
    />
    <ContentPresenter 
    Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type HeaderedContentControl}}}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"      
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I think in datatemplate you have to use FindAncestor as well

Comment: ContentPresenters are really meant exclusively for ControlTemplates, not DataTemplates.  Consider using a TextBlock and binding to the Text property.  Does the Command bind successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use [RelativeSource.AncestorLevel Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestorlevel). Default level is 1 and your WorkspacesTemplate `TabControl` is a `HeaderedContentControl` too. Try

```
Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.DisplayName,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type HeaderedContentControl},
                                                 AncestorLevel=2}}"
```

to find your real `HeaderedContentControl`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I add the AncestorLevel the DataContext of my MainWindow is used.

Comment: And your AllUserView is what? Where is it in your VisualTree?

Comment: AllUserView is the correct view. But the Command and the property are part of the AllUserViewModel.

Comment: The solution is set the Path to DataContext.DataContext... As I wrote the last comment, I got it :-) THX